# How to extract xml.stream source code from openjdk-7

Tags: android, xml, uml, android-library, java

I'm Trying to extract javax.xml.stream source code
that will be used for android  from openjdk-7.

But there is problem in dependency.

as I know, sources in javax.xml.stream.** have dependency on com.sun.** source,
However there are too many com.sun.** source files to select what I need.

any one who knows something useful tools to show dependency?

Comment: If you do this, be sure to honor the software license (GPL) of the OpenJDK. Also, bear in mind that your app may fail to build now or may break in the future, unless you repackage all of this code into some other package name (e.g., `com.user1621841.xml.stream`). I would recommend you use any of the other available XML parsers for Android -- there are three that ship with Android and others available as third-party JARs.

Comment: How does this relate with UML?